# Rules module: How do I execute code just before content is deleted?

Tags: database, rules

I'm trying to execute some code right before content is deleted. The Rules module has events for

- After updating existing content
- Before saving content
- After saving new content
- After deleting content

However, none of these execute my code at the right time. Is there a way to easily add new events? If so, where should I hook? My knowledge of the Drupal core is very small.

*Background:*

What I'm doing is updating a menu link that links to the content in the database, but as the update code only runs *after* having deleted the content, there isn't any row to be updated because Drupal apparently deletes menu items that link to non-existent content.

Comment: Is this for Drupal 6 or Drupal 7? In Drupal 6 the node is deleted and the delete hooks are then called. In 7 it's the other way around.

Comment: This is Drupal 7. The delete hooks appear to be executing too late, as the menu item will already have been deleted in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking to implement [hook_delete()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_delete/7).

You can also check [node_delete_multiple()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_delete_multiple/7) in node.module, if you want to have an idea of what Drupal core does when it delete nodes...there's other hooks that get called as well.